# How to check if NavigationGroup Favorites is shown in the NavigationPane in the MailModule?

Tags: vba, outlook, favorites

I want to check, if the NavigationGroup Favorites is shown in the NavigationPane in the MailModule.

The following VBA code shows the NavigationPane.

```vb
objOutlook.ActiveExplorer.ShowPane(OlPane.olNavigationPane, True)
```

How do I ensure that the Favorites are also shown?

This can only done manually by Click on View / Layout / Folder / Favorites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationmodule.visible) property to determine whether the navigation module is visible. As for the Navigation groups, you can use the [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationgroups.item) property which returns a `NavigationGroup` object from the collection. The index value of a `NavigationGroup` in the collection represents the ordinal position of the navigation group when displayed in the navigation pane. The [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationgroups.count) property returns an integer indicating the count of objects in the specified collection.

Comment: Hello Eugene, 
I have tried it. The NavigationGroup.Count is always 1, independent if I activate the Favorites in View / Layout / Folder or not. The Favorite Area seems not to be a NavigationGroup in the MailModule. But what else is the Favorite Area in the NavigationPane of the MailModule?
With the following code you get the Favorites NavigationGroup: 
objGroupFav = objMailModule.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olFavoriteFoldersGroup)
But I can't decide anything if it is visible or not.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) is the last resort I suppose in that case.